# Understanding JS arrays and splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

In JavaScript there are certain things that the language hides away but which do in fact impact performance. One example being that all strings in JavaScript are immutable, so concatenating strings over and over again can be a costly operation.

I was wondering how arrays are structured under the hood of JS. Are they array lists that are doubling or something smarter than that? And in particular when you call `splice()` to remove or insert elements is that creating a whole new array or is it shifting around all of the elements in the original array?

I looked around SO a bit but couldn't find any answers so I was hoping you all could help. Thanks!

Comment: I think it depend on the browser JS implementation

Comment: Arrays are mutable data structures, and [the example of `splice() on MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) clearly demonstrates that it is an in-place operation that mutates the array globally, so no, `splice()` doesn't create a new array (except to store the deleted items). As for specific implementation details - well, that's what you will hopefully get an answer to.

Comment: It definitely depends on the JS engine.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan to the JS I agree arrays are mutable data structures, but so are strings, whereas under the hood they actually aren't mutable. The mutability is abstracted and that's cross browser. I'd be inclined to think that core implementation doesn't vary that much, but then again I don't know which is why I asked the question :)

Comment: @winhowes I think you're getting slightly mixed up. What makes arrays mutable _under the hood_ is the fact that doing `var x = [1,2,3]; var y = x; x.push(6)` changes `y` as well. All references to the same array are modified everywhere. Strings, on the other hand, return a reference to a _new_ string on mutation, which is what makes them immutable: the _same_ string is not being altered.

Answer (score 0):

[GeeksForGeeks Detailed Explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-view-array-of-a-structure-in-javascript/)

The Javascript arrays are heterogeneous. The structure of the array is the same which is enclosed between two square brackets [ ], and string should be enclosed between either **“double quotes” or ‘single quotes’**. You can get the structure of by using **JSON.stringify()** or not, here you will see the use of **JSON.stringify().** For other procedure you can check this link.
Syntax:

```
JSON.stringify(value, replacer, space)
```

The Functionality of the alert() is to first give information to the user before gets proceeding further. So, in the below code, the button on click **function(Alert())** has two alerts **(alert())**, after displaying all the alerts it gets further with the webpage. By clicking ‘ok’ in the alert box it displays the next alert until all are done.

Comment: This answer doesn't touch on how arrays are implemented under the hood, which is what the question is getting at